# Two horizontally aligned, vertically centered divs

Tags: html, css

I have a problem that is driving me crazy.

I have a wrapper `div` that contains a div with some text, and an image.
The sizes of the image and the div vary.
The wrapper div adjust to the size of the larger one.

Both of them should be vertically aligned, like here:

[image]

I came across this post:
http://www.jakpsatweb.cz/css/css-vertical-center-solution.html

As you can see in the fiddle right here:
http://jsfiddle.net/nBXNg/4/ 
It does not work as expected

I'd be glad if someone could help me with this one.

Comment: Not expert enough to actually answer this, but I believe the floats are killing this. I've had more success with `inline-block` elements, which respect `vertical-align` the 'right way' (without `table-cell`). Though, `inline-block` comes with its own demons...

Comment: @akaIDIOT Thanks, however didn't work either: http://jsfiddle.net/nBXNg/5/

Comment: http://jsfiddle.net/nBXNg/8/ the 'right way' I mentioned means it is supposed to be applied to the element that needs to be aligned, not its parent (so: applying it to the `.greenBorder` does work, but spot the whitespace between the boxes, for example).

Comment: Thanks! I went with Morpheus's answer though, because sometimes I'm forced to do a float for Mobile Layout reasons. Have a wonderful day ;)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

All you have to do is wrap your each content into `.container` div. [Updated jsfiddle](http://jsfiddle.net/nBXNg/6/)

Comment: So simple, I can't believe I've missed that. Thanks a lot!